# how to implement in python in this problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7

Finds a list of unique words in text that start with a consonant
    (letters that are not vowels). Note: all words are returned as
    lowercase and are returned in no particular order.

```
Parameters
----------
in_str: string
    A sentence containing no punctuation.
    E.g. "A dog is a good pet and a bear is an awful pet"

Returns
-------
list of strings
    The words from the sentence that do not start with vowels
    ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].
    All strings are returned as lower case.

Examples
--------
>>> consonant_first("A dog is a good pet and a bear is an awful pet")
["dog", "good", "pet", "bear"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As StackOverflow is *not* a code-writing service, the next thing you should do is try to write some code yourself - and if you don’t know how to do that then go searching for a python tutorial because StackOverflow isn’t a tutorial site either. If your code doesn’t work, then come back here with a question about your code and why it doesn’t work.

Comment: Why is "pet" a unique word? I see it twice in the sentence.

Comment: @Matthias perhaps what they meant was that the returned list should only contain unique words.

Comment: I suggest reading about regular expressions (python `re` module), which could be used to accomplish this task.

Comment: You seem quite good at criticizing the “answers” with `assertionerror` without ever posting any code you have written. Please edit your code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is you should split the sentence based on " " to get the list of words. You can also lower case it at this point. The second checks to see if the first letter is a vowel. Since you don't want the vowel, you want to use not in.

```
def consonant_first(sentence):
    words = sentence.lower().split(" ")
    return [word for word in words if word[0] not in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]]
```

The interesting thing about this problem is that there's a multitude of ways to do it. The above shows the simplest way.

A more optimized approach may be to iterate over the sentence once. In the above, lower, split, and the for loop creates 3 iterations over the sentence.

An approach that just iterates once may be the following where we use logic to determine whether it's the first charter of the word to check if it's a vowel or to reset the current word when we encounter a space:

```
def consonant_first(sentence):
    current_word = ""
    words = []
    skip_word = False
    for ch in sentence:
        if current_word == "" and ch in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
            skip_word = True
        if skip_word == False and ch != " " and current_word != "":
            current_word += ch
        if ch == " ":
            if current_word != "":
                words.append(current_word)
            current_word = ""
            skip_word = False
    if current_word[0] not in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
        words.append(current_word)
    return words
```

Comment: AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != ['friend', 'my', 'peter', 'to', 'will']

Second list contains 5 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
'friend'

- []
+ ['friend', 'my', 'peter', 'to', 'will']

Comment: Can you rerun and show me what your input is? I updated the optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
vowels=['a','e','i','o','u']
aug=[]
def consonant_first(statement):
  words = statement.split()
  for word in words:
    word =word.lower()
    if(not word[0] in vowels):
      aug.append(word)



consonant_first("A dog is a good pet and a bear is an awful pet")
aug=list(dict.fromkeys(aug)) #remove duplicates
```

EDITED

Comment: AssertionError: Lists differ: ['friend', 'my', 'my', 'peter', 'to', 'will'] != ['friend', 'my', 'peter', 'to', 'will']

First differing element 2:
'my'
'peter'

First list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 5:
'will'

- ['friend', 'my', 'my', 'peter', 'to', 'will']
?                 ------

+ ['friend', 'my', 'peter', 'to', 'will']

Answer (score 0):

```
def consonant_first(Sentence):
list =['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
Sentence = Sentence.lower().split()
final_list = []
for element in Sentence:
    if element[0] not in list and element not in final_list:
        final_list.append(element)
return final_list
```

Try this (modified)

Comment: AssertionError: Lists differ: ['friend', 'my', 'my', 'peter', 'to', 'will'] != ['friend', 'my', 'peter', 'to', 'will']

First differing element 2:
'my'
'peter'

First list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 5:
'will'

- ['friend', 'my', 'my', 'peter', 'to', 'will']
?                 ------

+ ['friend', 'my', 'peter', 'to', 'will']

Comment: You can change the if statement to:  if (element[0] not in list) and (element not in final_list)

Answer (score 0):

```
def constant(word):
    vowels =['a','e','i','o','u']
    word = word.lower()

    constant_words = filter(lambda x: x[0] not in vowels, word.split())
    return [words for words in constant_words]
```

I sincerely hope you will not copy and paste this solution blindly for your assignment, but rather take time to understand how it works.

We first create a list of vowels, then transform every character in the string to lowercase.

We then use a filter function, to see if the first character of each word is a vowel. We do this via word.split(), where split() creates a list that uses a white space as a delimiter. This lets us create something like

```
['a', 'good', 'dog']
```